# VS Code C# syntax highlighting bug

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

using "Visual Studio Code 1.15.1";

I've been using VSCode on my Mac to view some C# code I had written elsewhere, and for some reason, certain things aren't highlighted correctly.

(0) `await` statements are not highlighted correctly when used with a variable instead of a method call or member accessor.

```
await someTask; // highlighted as if someTask were a variable of type await
await someThing.SomeTask; // highlighted correctly
await someThing.DoSomething(); // highlighted correctly
```

(1) `using` is highlighted as if it were a function instead of a keyword.

```
using (var spoon = new DisposableSpoon()) {
    // ...
}
```

which didn't happen before.

(2) Some C# 7 features aren't highlighted correctly, such as `out` variables.

```
if (map.TryGetValue(key, out TValue val)) {
    // ...
}
```

I'm using the default theme (Dark+), and I don't think I have any major, workspace-breaking plugins enabled (most are just extra themes or support for other languages). Did I accidentally mess up a config or something, or is this a bug?

**Edit:** (1) is fixed when I change the language from "C#" to "C# (official)". There seem to be multiple C#'s for some reason, but none seem to fix all of the aforementioned bugs. If this is just due to a wonky config or something, how would I revert to default?

Comment: eh, `out` isn't a C#7 feature, it's been part of the language for a long time.

Comment: I mean declaring a variable in the same spot as an out parameter, as shown above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The await issue seems like a bug in our built-in c# grammar. I've opened an issue with the grammar we use to track this: https://github.com/dotnet/csharp-tmLanguage/issues/83

I can only repo (1) when not within a class or method body, and I can't repo (2). Can you please file issues for these as well. Include the code, a screenshot, and a short explanation of what looks incorrect: https://github.com/dotnet/csharp-tmLanguage/issues/new

Comment: Alright, I'll file an issue tomorrow. Just to make sure, though, is it possible for extensions to somehow mess up default tmLanguages or something? If you can't reproduce it, then the latter two might just be issues on my end.

Comment: Update: After installing 1.16.0-Insider, I no longer see (1) and (2). Though  this isn't the main build, these two were probably just me.

Comment: Yes, extensions can override the built-in grammar for a language. That may be what happened to you with the `c# (official)` grammar

Comment: The only extension I recall installing [and subsequently disabling] was the C# for VSCode (Omnisharp) extension. The rest were either themes or extensions for other languages.